# Missing comma in "welcome back" message

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, grammar

The autologin message is missing a comma.

> Welcome back *user_name*, you've been logged in

should be:

> Welcome back**,** *user_name*, you've been logged in.

*user_name* is a vocative, expression of direct address, and should be separated from the rest of the sentence.

Comment: It is the difference between direct address and object. "Welcome back Kreiri" tells me to welcome back some other Kreiri, "Welcome back, Kreiri" greets me.

Comment: No, I, do, not, think, we, should, have, comma, after, each, word.

Comment: @Kreiri: fair enough; that makes sense.

Comment: @Shadow: this is not, about random, commas though, we are not, talking, about commas after every, word.

Comment: Some sources that support this: [iue.edu (item 6) *"Use a comma to indicate direct address"*](http://www.iue.edu/hss/writingcenter/documents/Commas.pdf) and [Wikipedia: Vocative case *For example, in the sentence, "I don't know, John," John is a vocative expression that indicates the party being addressed—as opposed to the sentence, "I don't know John," where John is the direct object of the verb "know."*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case)

Comment: While we're at it, the second comma should actually be a semicolon. "*Welcome back you've been logged in*" doesn't make any grammatical sense.

Comment: All wrong. All so very wrong. It should simply be *"No, we're not letting you in any more. You shouldn't have logged out in the first place"*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> While we're at it, the second comma should actually be a semicolon. "Welcome back you've been logged in" doesn't make any grammatical sense. –  Doorknob

Indeed!

Or, if you're me and you want to sidestep a semi-colon debate, you just split the message into two sentences:

> Welcome back, user_name. You've been logged in.

Going live in the next build.

Comment: I'm always actively on the lookout to sidestep a semi-colon debate!